# Copy one string into another

Tags: c, copy, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition

When the below piece of the code is run it is giving some kind of seg fault and program is crashing.
So initially temp = "abcdef"  and finally temp3 should also contain "abcdef"

```
My intention is to copy the content of "temp" into
 "temp3".Please suggest where I am doing wrong.
```

```
void fun (char * input , char **input1) {

size_t size = strlen(input);
*input1 = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char) * (size+1));
memcpy(*input1 , input , size);
}

int main(){

char * temp = "abcdef";
char * temp3;

fun(temp , temp3);
printf("%s",temp3);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings ... and mind them! Also you need to allocate `strlen + 1` for the terminating `'\0'`

Comment: This won't compile. As for the problem, it's the same old boring "off by 1 didn't allocate space for the null terminator" FAQ that's been answered countless times before. I can't be bothered to find a duplicate.

Comment: Also `input1 = malloc` is a bug, should be `*input1`. Remember why you passed it as `char**` to begin with.

Comment: Close voters: this is more than just a typo.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yeah it's 3 typos.

Comment: @All I take all suggestions from all . No this program is compiling without second thought . Issue is this is crashing.

Comment: I don't know why it has been downvoted . I had some typos which I made it correct.

Comment: When learning C you absolutely must compile with for example `gcc -Werror`. The current code has 4 warnings in gcc. Run with -Werror and that's 4 errors pointing out the exact locations of bugs in your code.

Comment: As for why it was down-voted... I down-voted because it lacks research, such as running the code through a compiler and reading the compiler log. A good question would ask about the compiler errors/warnings you got but didn't understand, by posting those in the question. A bad question asks random Internet people to be your compiler.

Comment: @Lundin I appreciate your effort for some research and I am thanking for you for this.I ran this code on codeblocks IDE which uses GCC compiler . As far as warnings are concerned , I agree that there are some warnings in it. But on codeblock there are no errors as such . The flgas that u are saying can be used in linux while running it. I have to see how I can enable these flags in codeblock IDE.

Comment: @ashwinak Settings -> Compiler -> Compiler flags tab. Check the following: "Enable all common compiler warnings (overrides many other settings) -Wall", "Enable extra compiler warnings -Wextra", "Treat as errors the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++ -pedantic-errors". You might have to add a custom one for -Werror.

Comment: As for "it only gave me a warning" please check [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277340)

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for this.I learnt this. "Popular compilers such as gcc, clang and icc can be configured to always produce errors instead of warnings, in case of syntax or constraint violations, by using -std=c11 -pedantic-errors which forces these compilers into a strict mode. I strongly recommend beginners learning the language to compile with these settings."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the second argument of the function

```
void fun (char * input , char **input1) {
```

has the type `char **` while you are passing an expression of the type `char *`.

```
char * temp3;

fun(temp , temp3);
```

So already the program has undefined behavior. You need to call the function like

```
fun(temp , &temp3);
```

Within the function you have to write at least the following

```
size_t size = strlen(input) + 1;
*input1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
memcpy( *input1 , input , size);
```

That is you need to count the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the source string.

And the first parameter of the function should have the qualifier `const`

```
void fun ( const char * input , char **input1);
```

In the end of the program you should free the allocated memory in the function

```
free( temp3 );
```

It would be more safer to check whether the memory was allocated successfully. For example

```
void fun( const char * input , char **input1 )
{
    size_t size = strlen(input) + 1;
    *input1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

    if ( *input1 ) memcpy( *input1 , input , size);
}
```

and in main you could write

```
fun(temp , &temp3);
if ( temp3 ) puts( temp3 );

free( temp3 );
```